# Multivariate sample covariance

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance, covariance-matrix, sample, multivariate-distribution

I have a set of $X_1,...,X_n$ samples with covariance $\Sigma_1,...,\Sigma_n$.
The multivariate sample mean is then $$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma_i^{-1} \right)^{-1} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma_i^{-1} X_i \right).$$
The covariance is $$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma_i^{-1} \right)^{-1}. $$
However, I cannot find a formula for the sample covariance where each sample has a different covariance. In the following wikipedia article, there is a formula for the weighted samples covariance matrix, but that is not quite what I am looking for:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance

Is there any reference on the subject ?

**EDIT:** I guess to make sense of what I asked, I need to change the problem. So instead of having covariance $\Sigma_i$, the $X_i$ have covariance $\sigma \Sigma_i$, where $\sigma$ is my unknown: the multivariate sample mean has the same formula, and the covariance is $\sigma \times ( \sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma_i^{-1} )^{-1}$.
I now collect a bunch of data, and I want to know the value of $\sigma$ using the data. If the $X_i$ were i.i.d., I would use the formula of the wikipedia article: $$Q = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})(X_i-\bar{X})^T.$$
If they are not i.i.d., and for example they have different weights (the case $\Sigma_i = w_i I_n$), I would use the formula $$Q=\frac{1}{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i (X_i-\bar{X})(X_i-\bar{X})^T.$$
Now I am in a more complex case where $\Sigma_i$ is not diagonal. The new constraint I am adding in this edit is that I know the "shape" of the $\Sigma_i$, I am just missing a scaling $\sigma$ on my covariance. Is there any generalized formula of the formulas above for non-diagonal covariance matrices ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time interpreting this question because you use the words "sample" and "covariance" in at least two distinct senses: "sample" seems to refer to both a multivariate observation and to a collection of such observations; while "covariance" seems to refer to a parameter of a distribution and to a sample statistic (maybe?). Perhaps you could offer a small example to clarify what you're asking about.

Comment: Yes, sorry it is not my main field so the definitions are too loose in my head.
I have seen an example which fits my case, so I am going to try and use this one.
Imagine I have ten different studies doing different experiments to measure the effect sizes A and B. Each study then provides a mean for A, a mean for B, and a covariance matrix for X = (A, B), hence a 2x2 matrix.
When trying to combine these studies, for a meta-analysis, the formula above give the combined mean and the combined covariance of the studies. I am looking instead to determine the empirical (or sample) covariance.

Comment: You say *where each sample has a different covariance*, but in your formulas that seems to be the case?

Comment: Indeed, so I edited the question to make it more precise, and to try to make sense. So I am now looking to determine a factor on my covariance, that I want to derive from data.